# sql order by clause

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok so in my database I have,

1,2,3,4

But what I really want is,

2,1,4,3.

so how do I order a column against a predefined set of sequence of strings or values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a order by column, and order the results based on that.